# Implement fuzzy search in a sharepoint portal

Tags: sharepoint, search, portal, fuzzy-search

I am developing a sharepoint portal for a suggestions and rewards system and need to alert duplicate suggestions. Suggestions will be in free text format, hence need fuzzy search. I understand that “Damerau-Levenshtein algorithm” does fuzzy search, but how do I implement in Sharepoint portal? Can Microsoft Search Server help? If yes, how ?

Answer (score 0):

You're kinda stuck with the built in Search provided by SharePoint, but the FullTextSqlQuery class can do a lot of waht you are looking for I think. It will filter out duplicates if you want to. I suggest you take a look at this class.

Trimming duplicates can be enabled / disabled using FullTextSqlQuery.TrimDuplicates = false or true

Comment: P.S. There are some third party products out therethat do leverage SharePoint Search OOTB functionality, like Coveo Enterprise Search.